# ASP.NET and GAC

Tags: asp.net, dll, gac

There is an ASP.NET Web application that makes use of a reference DLL. The same DLL is registered in GAC.

Is there a way to force VS or ASP.NET application to make use of the referenced DLL inside Bin folder rather than using the one in GAC?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik, the only way is to remove the one in the GAC

Comment: Thanks you colleagues for providing me with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove the assembly from the GAC or give the assembly in the bin directory a different name, version, culture, or strong name key to get the assembly in the bin directory to load.

Answer (score -1):

I've created a sexy visual studio extension that will help you to achieve your goal. [Muse VSReferences](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/36a6eb45-a7b1-47c3-9e85-09f0aef6e879/) will allow you to add a Global Assembly Cache reference to the project from Add GAC Reference menu item.

[image: screenshot]